# Laravel 4 seed returns successful but nothing in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working with Laravel 4 and trying to seed the database with some users.  I'm using the [Zizaco Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) plugin, so my `User` model extends `ConfideUser` instead of `Eloquent` per the documentation.  I added a few fields to the model also, but nothing super complicated.  I have tried removing those fields but I get the same issue.

I created a `UserSeeder` class that I call with the `DatabaseSeeder` and then run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.  It runs without error and returns "The database has been seeded", and that is true for every table except `users`.  No users ever get inserted.  I've tried creating the user with `User::create(array(...))` as well as `$user = new User ... $user->save()` and I get the same results.  No errors are dumped, and nothing is in any log I can find on the system.  If I insert some var_dumps in the UserSeeder->run() method, I see that the objects are created with the correct values, but nothing saves.

What am I missing?  Here's some code samples, I can provide more if needed:

models\User.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

//class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
class User extends ConfideUser
{
    // for Entrust
    use \Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function agency()
    {
        if ($this->agency_type == 'local')
        {
            return $this->hasOne('Local');
        }

        if ($this->agency_type == 'county')
        {
            return $this->hasOne('County');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

database\migrations\xxxxxxxxx_confide_setup_users_table.php:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ConfideSetupUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Creates the users table
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('confirmation_code');
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
            $table->string('address1');
            $table->string('address2')->nullable();
            $table->string('state', 2);
            $table->string('zipcode', 9);
            $table->string('phone', 10);
            $table->string('extension',5 )->nullable();
            $table->string('fax', 10)->nullable();
            $table->enum('agency_type', array('local', 'county', 'state'))->default('local');
            $table->integer('agency')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('last_seen');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

        // Creates password reminders table
        Schema::create('password_reminders', function($t)
        {
            $t->string('email');
            $t->string('token');
            $t->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('password_reminders');
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

database\seeds\UserSeeder.php:

```
<?php

use \Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(
            array(
                'username' => 'local_test',
                'email' => 'nathan@abc.com',
                'password' => Hash::make('local'),
                'confirmation_code' => '483JU3ID8',
                'confirmed' => true,
                'address1' => '123 Main St.',
                'state' => 'MI',
                'zipcode' => '12345',
                'phone' => '5559993436',
                'agency_type' => 'local',
                'agency' => null,
                'last_seen' => new DateTime
            )
        );
```

Comment: When using Confide you need to insert using DB:: because it has special validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in your user seeder class:

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

     DB::table('users')->truncate();



        $users = array(
        array(  'username' => 'local_test',
            'email' => 'nathan@abc.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('local'),
            'confirmation_code' => '483JU3ID8',
            'confirmed' => true,
            'address1' => '123 Main St.',
            'state' => 'MI',
            'zipcode' => '12345',
            'phone' => '5559993436',
            'agency_type' => 'local',
            'agency' => null,
            'last_seen' => new DateTime
                )
        );

             // make sure you do the insert
         DB::table('users')->insert($users);

}
}
```

and then,  make sure you invoke it in your DatabaseSeeder.php file

```
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {           
        $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

Comment: I got an error with `truncate()` because of some foreign key references, but if I keep that as `delete()` and use the array method you suggest, it works.  Can you explain why that works and `User::create()` and `$user = new User ... $user->save()` do not?

Comment: I don't know really.. I have used this before and I knew it would work.. but even in the docs the example is written with the way you pointed out: http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding .. I am wondering if it would work if you just extended `Eloquent` instead of `ConfideUser`

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you! I should have known it was Confide doing special validation that was blocking my seed functions.

Answer (score 1):

Confide uses Ardent for validation. adding 'password_confirmation' property is required. Also you don't need to Hash::make since Confide will also handle that for you.

```
<?php

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        DB::table('users')->truncate();

        $users = array(
        array(  'username' => 'local_test',
            'email' => 'nathan@abc.com',
            'password' => 'local',
            'password_confirmation' => 'local',
            'confirmation_code' => '483JU3ID8',
            'confirmed' => true,
            'address1' => '123 Main St.',
            'state' => 'MI',
            'zipcode' => '12345',
            'phone' => '5559993436',
            'agency_type' => 'local',
            'agency' => null,
            'last_seen' => new DateTime
                )
        );

         // make sure you do the insert
         DB::table('users')->insert($users);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the seeder fails silently.

I was seeing a user table. The return was a seed success but it was empty.
I followed the answer above using the insert method.
When doing the above method, an error was returned saying that a column did not have a default value in the database table.

I adjusted the column and reverted back to the create method from the laravel doc.
It was then successful.

So in my instance the there was a database error but it failed without telling me.
With the insert method I was able to find the error.
Then the create method worked once there were no errors.